# How to replace a nested list in multi-dimensional array python with another list based on a certain condition

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to replace a nested list in my_list on a certain condition. In this case, I want to replace the `'HB2_DF_en1a'` with the element of 2nd list and so on for the rest, if it finds `''` in the previous list. The number of `''` and elements in the 2nd list are the same.

```
my_list = [[[['', ''], ['HB2_DF_en1a', 'HB2_DF_en2a']]],
           [[[''], ['XY1_DF_en1a']],
            [['Io01[4:2]'], ['XY_DF1']]],
           [[['', ''], ['XY2_DF_en1a', 'XY2_DF_en2a']]]]
2nd_list = [['XY1_IPC'],
            ['cat_lpm'],
            ['XY_ABC1'],
            ['XY2_IPC'],
            ['XY_ABC2', 'XY2_IPC']]
```

I am trying -

```
b = 0
for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        for k in j:
                if a == '':
                    k+1.append(2nd_list[b])
                    b = b+1
```

The output I am looking for -

```
my_list = [[[['', ''], [['XY1_IPC'], ['cat_lpm']]]],
           [[[''], ['XY_ABC1']]],
            [['Io01[4:2]'], ['XY_DF1']],
           [[['', ''],
            [['XY2_IPC'], ['XY_ABC2', 'XY2_IPC']]]]]
```

Comment: Your list structure seems pretty arbitrary and inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like this:**

```
my_list = [
    [[["", ""], ["HB2_DF_en1a", "HB2_DF_en2a"]]],
    [[[""], ["XY1_DF_en1a"]], [["Io01[4:2]"], ["XY_DF1"]]],
    [[["", ""], ["XY2_DF_en1a", "XY2_DF_en2a"]]],
]
reference_list = [
    ["XY1_IPC"],
    ["cat_lpm"],
    ["XY_ABC1"],
    ["XY2_IPC"],
    ["XY_ABC2", "XY2_IPC"],
]


ref_index = 0
for level1 in my_list:
    for level2 in level1:
        for index, value in enumerate(level2):
            if value[0] == "":
                for change_index, times in enumerate(value):
                    level2[1][change_index] = reference_list[ref_index]
                    ref_index = ref_index + 1


# Print result:
print(my_list)
```

**Result:**

```
[
    [
        [
            ['', ''],
            [
                ['XY1_IPC'],
                ['cat_lpm']
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [''],
            [
                ['XY_ABC1']
            ]
        ],
        [
            ['Io01[4:2]'],
            ['XY_DF1']
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            ['', ''],
            [
                ['XY2_IPC'],
                ['XY_ABC2', 'XY2_IPC']
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```